How much kinetic energy from a micrometeorite is necessary to destroy a Starlink satellite?
Apparently, spacecraft getting hit by micrometeorites is very common. There are more Starlink satellites then every other satellites, combined, so I’d imagine they’ll get hit at some point (if they haven’t already). So, roughly, how much kinetic energy from a micrometeorite is needed to destroy a Starlink satellite (prevent it from doing its job)? If it’s different) I am interested in the energy needed for the v1.0, v1.5, and the v2 mini. Assume it hits the weakest part of the satellite.

What are you planning.

Nothing in particular, why? @DarthPseudonym

@GregMiller done

Can’t do it job @Cadence

"Assume it hits the weakest part" is a very loaded statement. With arbitrarily high precision, you could likely strike the insulation of the wiring which connects the solar panel DC power to the main satellite body, and, if done properly, do it in such a way which shorts the panels and renders the satellite incapable of generating power.

A grain of sand travelling at orbital velocities could puncture the satellite's inert gas propellant tank (ref).



The leaking propellant could put the satellite into a spin effectively rendering it useless.
The kinetic energy of a grain of sand travelling at orbital velocities is approximately...
$$E=0.5mv^2=0.5(3 \times 10^{-10}kg)(8000 m/s)^2 = 0.0096\ Joules$$
For reference, 1 Joule is the amount of electricity required to light a 1 watt LED for 1 s.
